# Gracefully closing an inactive TCP connection

Tags: tcp, ip-conntrack

Does exist a command to "gracefully" close a TCP connection opened by a process before it reaches its timeout?

I would like to gracefully close all those TCP connections in a CLOSE_WAIT/TIME_WAIT state that are present in the *netfilter connection tracking table* before they reach their timeout.

By graceful I mean the same behavior I have when I *close* a socket from a program.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what operating system your on. But, while there's probably a more elegant way to do this. The following might help. If you were to use sockstat(1), or procstat(1) on a BSD system. You could easily derive the pid that connection is running under, and simply issue a `kill -HUP <pid number>`

Where `<pid number>` is the pid the process is running as/under.

See also:

[sockstat](https://manpage.me/?q=sockstat)

[procstat](https://manpage.me/?q=procstat)

[kill](https://manpage.me/?q=kill)

HTH

Comment: Does _kill -HUP_ close the TCP connection gracefully by removing it from the _conntrack_ table?